# Bar Room Scrap Interpretation

Tags: geometry, popular-math

I was given this years ago while at a local tavern.  I called it the Lloyd Intersection. [Scrap Original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ZH1UFSBOZ6OHZ2dDVQQ1ByOTNRNlNScHkyOUl6R01TMXFn/view?usp=drivesdk)

What is this question?

My work so far. [Interpretation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ZH1UFSBOZ6WjB4aFBuV195dVI1ZUUxM2FnWVNZdGRITDNN/view?usp=drivesdk)

I believe this may be asking us to;  *Explain a method that can be used to solve for the given value of x.*  What has been given can be proven to be true.  [GeoGebra 1/5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nXiGwnBn0uBf8OV52FuagLLW7MZOFOiP/view?usp=drivesdk)

My method  for solving for x was to  use the integers, 2 and 4 as the diameters of two circles on an x and y axis. 
[Courtesy GeoGebra  1/5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lECsy4OM-WZvaT0vtg8fe8bug_JTr0DW/view?usp=drivesdk) These two circles intersect at two points, the origin, and at the point (x, 0).   How much the circles intersect is determined by a point on the line y=5, where the diameters intersect.  I have experimented with different graphic repesentations of this problem. [Lloyd intersection mirror](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mbsjw0GU536ogpjvvp57FumEzQD9yak5/view?usp=drivesdk) and come to the conclusion you need to discover what the distance is between the centers of the two circles. This will lead to the numeric solution for x  that I was after.

Comment: That scrap has been posted here before. It is still the classical [Crossed Ladders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_ladders_problem) problem.

Comment: Yes Jens, this scrap was posted here before.  I removed it because it was so poorly written.  I have enjoyed  working with the crossed ladders theorem that you have intoduced me to and I thank you.